# Should a stochastic process satisfy this condition?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a stochastic process. Let 
$$M_n(a_1,\dotsc, a_n; t_1, \dotsc, t_n) = \mathbb{E}e^{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_{t_i}},\,$$
where $t_i,\, 1\le i \le n$ are distinct.

1. Is it essential that $$\lim_{h_1\to 0,\dotsc, h_n\to 0}M_n(a_1, \dotsc, a_n; t+h_1,\dotsc, t+h_n) = M_1\left(\sum_{i=1} a_i; t\right)$$ Almost every process that I can think of including Levy processes, Gaussian process satisfy this condition.
2. If the answer to the above question is no, I was wondering about the implication of a process not satisfying this condition.

### Example

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Gaussian process with mean function $\mu$ and covariance function $\Sigma$. Then
$$M_n(a_1,\dotsc, a_n; t_1,\dotsc, t_n) = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(t_i) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j \Sigma(t_i, t_j) \right)$$

Moreover, $$\lim_{h_1\to 0,\dotsc, h_n\to 0}M_n(a_1, \dotsc, a_n; t+h_1,\dotsc, t+h_n) = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(t) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j \Sigma(t, t) \right) = M_1(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i; t)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.  Let $X_t$ be the process that is $0$ for all $t \leq 1$ and $1$ for all $t > 1$.  Then
$$M_1(a;t) = E[e^{aX_t}]$$
This function is $1$ for $t \leq 1$ and $e^a$ for $t>1$.
Now your condition is violated with $n = 1$ and $a \neq 0$ as $t$ approaches $1$ from the right.
$$e^a = \lim_{h \to 0} M_1(a; 1+h) \neq M_1(a;1) = 1$$

The key to this example is that there is a discontinuous jump in the "density" of the process at time $t = 1$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reply.